# Matlab: Looping through an array

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

This is my one dimensional array `A`. containing 10 numbers

```
A = [-8.92100000000000 10.6100000000000 1.33300000000000 ...
     -2.57400000000000 -4.52700000000000 9.63300000000000 ...
     4.26200000000000 16.9580000000000 8.16900000000000 4.75100000000000];
```

I want the loop to go through like this;
(calculating mean interval wise) - Interval length of 2,4,8

1. `(a(1)+a(2))/2` - value stored in one block of a matrix say m= zeros(10)
2. then `(a(1)+a(2)+a(3)+a(4))/4` ------ mean-----
3. then `(a(1)+a(2)..... a(8))/8`

then shift index;

1. `(a(2)+a(3))/2;` - mean
2. `(a(2)+a(3)+a(4)+a(5))/4`
3. `(a(2)+a(3)...a(9))/8`

> **SO basically 2^n length interval**

Comment: There will 19 mean values total.

Comment: Standard deviation and co variance too! of these intervals

Comment: i have now a 64x256 matrix. i need to calculate mean_2 for the first row separately, then second row and so now, im2col seems to go down the column, i want it to go row wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [`conv`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) without loops

```
avg_2 = mean([A(1:end-1);A(2:end)])

avg_4 = conv(A,ones(1,4)/4,'valid')

avg_8 = conv(A,ones(1,8)/8,'valid')
```

**Output for the sample Input:**

```
avg_2 =
0.8445    5.9715   -0.6205   -3.5505    2.5530    6.9475   10.6100   12.5635    6.4600

avg_4 =
0.1120    1.2105    0.9662    1.6985    6.5815    9.7555    8.5350

avg_8 =
3.3467    5.4830    4.7506
```

Finding **Standard Deviation** for an example (`std_4`)

```
%// each 1x4 sliding sub-matrix is made a column
%// for eg:- if A is 1x6 you would get 1-2-3-4, 2-3-4-5, 3-4-5-6 each as a column
%// ending with 3 columns. for 1x10 matrix, you would get 7 columns
reshaped_4 = im2col(A,[1 4],'sliding');    %// change 4 to 2 or 8 for other examples

%// calculating the mean of every column
mean_4 = mean(reshaped_4);

%// Subtract each value of the column with the mean value of corresponding column
out1 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_4,mean_4);

%// finally element-wise squaring, mean of each column 
%// and then element-wise sqrt to get the output.
std_4 = sqrt(mean(out1.^2))
```

**Output for the sample Input:**

```
std_4 =

7.0801    5.8225    5.4304    5.6245    7.8384    4.5985    5.0906
```

**Full code for OP**

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

A = [-8.92100000000000 10.6100000000000 1.33300000000000 ...
     -2.57400000000000 -4.52700000000000 9.63300000000000 ...
     4.26200000000000 16.9580000000000 8.16900000000000 4.75100000000000];

reshaped_2 = im2col(A,[1 2],'sliding'); %// Length Two 
mean_2 = mean(reshaped_2); 
out1 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_2,mean_2); 
std_2 = sqrt(mean(out1.^2)) 
reshaped_4 = im2col(A,[1 4],'sliding'); %// Four 
mean_4 = mean(reshaped_4); 
out1 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_4,mean_4); 
std_4 = sqrt(mean(out1.^2)) 
reshaped_8 = im2col(A,[1 8],'sliding'); %// Eight 
mean_8 = mean(reshaped_8); 
out1 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_8,mean_8); 
std_8 = sqrt(mean(out1.^2))
```

Comment: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. - Error?

Comment: What if i have multiple rows of numbers, for that i will need a loop yes?

Comment: @HarshSharma There is `conv2` for 2 dimensional arrays and `convn` for multi-dimensional arrays. You don't need a loop!! ;)

Comment: @HarshSharma haha! for more examples, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+conv) BTW, If you find this answer helpful, consider accepting this answer

Comment: @HarshSharma - `conv` is actually used for polynomial multiplication.  It's one of the most common uses for it, so you are correct.

Comment: @rayryeng Then how is conv() used here, this is confusing.

Comment: @HarshSharma - In this case, you can consider your input as being expressed as a `nth` order polynomial being polynomially multiplied with a polynomial that is `mth` order of all 1/4 or 1/8 if `m=4 or 8`.  That's how you would mathematically look at it... but from a signal processing viewpoint, you collect windows of 4 or 8 values and you find the average within this window and set it to the output.  It's best to think about it a signal processing context.  Don't look at it in the polynomial context... that's just a bonus.

Comment: @HarshSharma Here's an example: `x = [1 2 1], y = [1 1]`. Using `conv`, you can think of this as `(x^2 + 2x + 1)*(x + 1) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1`.  Doing `z = conv(x, y)` gives you `[1 3 3 1]`.  The output is the polynomial coefficients of the multiplication once you're finished.  As I said again, don't think about it in terms of a polynomial multiplication.  Look at this in a signal processing viewpoint.  It's easier to understand.

Comment: yea i think its right, but it is still showing me Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: @HarshSharma do you have a variable name `mean` in your workspace? Add `clear` if front of the code and create a new script and repeat. updated code i think it will work now

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Hey man. i have now a 62x256 matrix. i need to calculate mean_2 for the first row separately, then second row and so now, im2col seems to go down the column, i want it to go row wise?

Comment: @SanthanSalai 64x256*